# Accessing nested ManyToMany fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three models: Food, Meal, and MealPlan.

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default="food")
    calories = models.FloatField(validators=[validate_positive])
    fat = models.FloatField(validators=[validate_positive])
    carbs = models.FloatField(validators=[validate_positive])
    protein = models.FloatField(validators=[validate_positive])

class Meal(models.Model):
    foods = models.ManyToManyField(Food)

    @property
    def totalcals(self):
        sum = self.foods.aggregate(models.Sum('calories'))['calories__sum']
        if sum == None:
            return 0
        else:
            return sum

class MealPlan(models.Model):
    meals = models.ManyToManyField(Meal)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=14, default= "")

    @property
    def totalcals(self):
         sum = self.meals.foods.totalcals(models.Sum('totalcals'))['totalcals__sum']
        if sum == None:
            return 0
        else:
            return sum
```

The first totalcals property works properly. The second one causes an error. I want the second totalcals in MealPlan to return all of its meals totalcals summed up. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can not chain two M2M relations as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be self.meals.totalcals...not self.meals.foods.totalcals?  Food doesn't have a property of totalcals but Meal does.

```
@property
def totalcals(self):
  sum = self.meals.totalcals(models.Sum('totalcals'))['totalcals__sum']
```

Comment: I get this error now: Cannot resolve keyword 'totalcals' into field. I think it's because totalcals is a property, rather than a field.

Comment: You can not pass argument to a property!. Try `sum = self.meals.totalcals`

Comment: FallenAngel is right.  Access the property where you've already created the logic of summing.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
@property
def totalcals(self):
   sum = 0
   for meal in self.meals.all():
       sum = sum + meal.totalcals

   if sum = 0:
       return None
   else:
       return sum
```

But I guess there would be a shorter answer as well.